# what does "=>" means in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript OD, the code like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );
var maxCallback = ( pre, cur ) => Math.max( pre.x, cur.x );
```

I have searched in Google with "=> in Javascript", but patched nothing, 
what does it mean?

Comment: It refers to an arrow function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). If this is brand new to you, you should google ES6 JS features.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866037/what-does-mean-in-javascript-equals-greater-than